# How to return one of two possible templated object types in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-erasure

I have created a minimal example based on my complicated project that is using boost:

```
template<typename T>
struct Data {
    T attribute;

    void print() {}
};

typedef Data<int> IntDataType;
typedef Data<float> FloatDataType;

std::shared_ptr<IntDataType> make_int_data() {
    return std::make_shared<IntDataType>();
}

std::shared_ptr<FloatDataType> make_float_data() {
    return std::make_shared<FloatDataType>();
}

std::any data;

void create_data(bool useFloat) {
    if (useFloat)
        data = make_float_data();
    else
        data = make_int_data();
}

auto get_data() {
    try {
        auto c = std::any_cast<FloatDataType>(data);
        return c;
    }
    catch (std::bad_any_cast const& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << '\n';
    }

    auto c = std::any_cast<IntDataType>(data);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    create_data(true);
    get_data().print();
    return 0;
}
```

I have **Data** type that is based on a templated argument and I am created two Data types based on that: **IntDataType** and **FloatDataType**.
I have a global variable **std::any** that could contain both of my types and sure I could try to cast to one type and to another.

The problem is that I am using these casts in a lot of places and the code is a mess. And as a result, I want to create a function that could return any of these types and make a simple call of method that is common for both (int our case **print()**).
In my case this is a **get_data()** but it gives an error:

> inconsistent deduction for auto return type: Data<float> and then Data<int>

I could not change the types because they are part of the boost library in my case. Is there a way to do it using modern C++? Will appreciate any help.

Comment: The return type has to be known at compile time, with `std::any_cast` you can't satisfy this requirement. You might want to reconsider your approach. One thing that comes to mind is `std::variant` + `std::visit`.

Comment: I could also create templated class and at the moment when I create it I already know what data type it should be, I think it will work, right?

Comment: You don't agree with what? That the return type should be known at compile time? This is a fundamental requirement of C++. "Known" doesn't mean "has to be specified explicitly", it also includes type deduction. But `std::any` erases a type making type deduction at compile time impossible.

Comment: What kind of things do you want to do with your data? Because I think you're design is not going the right direction (mixing compile time concepts with runtime behavior). In C++ you cannot specialize functions based on return type (and as said the return type must be known at compile time).

Comment: If I read such code I got no implression what it is good for. It seems to be an abuse of std::any, templates and all the run time switch/if/else/ and especially all the cast stuff. No idea what is the sense behind and what is the idea behind it. We also have no idea what you really want to achieve. In a short: Looks like a general misunderstanding of run time and compile time programming. Maybe simply a big design bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::variant<std::shared_ptr<IntDataType>, std::shared_ptr<FloatDataType>> data;
void create_data(bool useFloat) {
    if (useFloat)
        data = make_float_data();
    else
        data = make_int_data();
}
```

```
std::visit([](auto& elem) { elem->print(); }, data);
```

`std::variant` can be used in more complex cases, I wrote about it once in my blog:

[Design Patterns: RunTime Reflection – C++](https://cppsenioreas.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/design-patterns-runtime-reflection-cpp/)

**Edit:**
An easier approach (as @PepijnKramer mentioned that is possible in that case) would be a common non-templated interface. Notice that it won't always be the case, and `std::variant` would usually be the easiest solution.

```
struct DataI {
    virtual ~DataI() = default;
    virtual void print() {};
};

template<typename T>
struct Data : DataI {
    T attribute;
};

std::shared_ptr<DataI> data;

void create_data(bool useFloat) {
    if (useFloat)
        data = make_float_data();
    else
        data = make_int_data();
}
```

Another approach, in case that you don't want to use virtual tables, is a common template base class collection, introduced by Sean Parent. I also wrote about it:

[Template Base Class Collection](https://cppsenioreas.wordpress.com/2020/08/30/template-base-class-collection/)

Comment: Or just have overloads (or templated version) for print and visit is not necessary

Comment: @PepijnKramer this print function version is easy, and allows you to go around it more easily, but if it was touched in its signature by the template parameter, it wouldn't be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a function that could return any of these types and make a simple call of method that is common for both

This is exactly the kind of situation that polymorphism is meant to solve.

Common methods should be declared in a base class that derived types implement, and then you can return a pointer to that base class and call the common methods without having to know the derived type.

```
struct BaseData {
    virtual ~BaseData() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Data : BaseData {
    T attribute;

    void print() override { ... }
};

typedef Data<int> IntDataType;
typedef Data<float> FloatDataType;

std::shared_ptr<IntDataType> make_int_data() {
    return std::make_shared<IntDataType>();
}

std::shared_ptr<FloatDataType> make_float_data() {
    return std::make_shared<FloatDataType>();
}

std::shared_ptr<BaseData> data;

void create_data(bool useFloat) {
    if (useFloat)
        data = make_float_data();
    else
        data = make_int_data();
}

auto get_data() {
    return data;
}

int main() {
    create_data(true);
    get_data()->print();

    create_data(false);
    get_data()->print();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/KPCJ3OaSW)